# How to open and close a modal after 3 seconds without Bootstrap or Jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm new to learning JavaScript and I'm trying to open then close a custom message after 3 seconds of appearing but my function doesn't work. The message appears but does not disappear... can you help me find the solution  because I can't find it alone.
Thanks very much !

```js
const confirmationMessage = document.getElementById("message_validation");

// launch confirmationMessage form 
const launchConfirmationMessage = () => {
  confirmationMessage.style.display = "flex";
}

//close confirmationMessage form
const closeConfirmationMessage = () => {
  confirmationMessage.style.display = "none";
}

// TimeOut du confirmationMessage
const timeOutConfirmMess = () => {
  setTimeout(closeConfirmationMessage, 3000);
}


// open and close window after 3s
function confirm() {
  if (launchConfirmationMessage() = true && closeConfirmationMessage() === false) {
    timeOutConfirmMess();
  }
}
console.log(confirm());
```

```css
.message-validation {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 13%;
  top: 41%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(26, 39, 156, 0.9);
  color: white;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="message_validation" class="message-validation">
  Bravo! Votre réservation est prise en compte.
</div>
```

Also, basically the css element is in display:none and it is during a condition that it becomes display:block
like this:

```
if (isOk){ confirm();}
```

Thanks you again !

Comment: PS : (isOk) value is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your if statement is not correct. In a if statement you always compaire two things and you use "==" or "===". You also doesn't return any values in your helper function.

For this code I wouldn't recommend a helper function, the code below will work.

```js
const confirmationMessage = document.getElementById("message_validation");
// open and close window after 3s
function confirm () {
  confirmationMessage.style.display = "flex";
  setTimeout(() => {
      confirmationMessage.style.display = "none";
  }, 3000)

}
  console.log(confirm());
```

Answer (score 0):

call `setTimeout` with 3000 milliseconds immediately you show the confirmationMessage. That way, the close function will be called after 3 seconds. `confirm` function is hence unnecessary, so I removed it. The following works.

```js
const confirmationMessage = document.getElementById("message_validation");

// launch confirmationMessage form 
const launchConfirmationMessage = () => {
  confirmationMessage.style.display = "flex";
  setTimeout(closeConfirmationMessage, 3000);
}

//close confirmationMessage form
const closeConfirmationMessage = () => {
 confirmationMessage.style.display = "none";
}

launchConfirmationMessage();
```

```css
.message-validation{
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 13%;
  top: 41%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(26, 39, 156, 0.9);
  color: white;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="message_validation" class="message-validation">
   Bravo! Votre réservation est prise en compte.
 </div>
```

Also, in your `confirm` function, that `if` statement will never return `true` because the functions don't return boolean values.

So instead of using the `confirm` function. Simply call `launchConfirmationMessage` when `isOk` is true. I called it at once in the snippet for you to see that it works, but in your codebase you can use the following instead.

```js
if (isOk) {
  launchConfirmationMessage();
}
```

Comment: okay great, please mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is this if clause:

```js
if (launchConfirmationMessage() = true && closeConfirmationMessage() === false){ 
  // ... 
}
```

There are more than one errors:

1. The functions you call do not have any return values, so `closeConfirmationMessage() === false` will never be true, and `launchConfirmationMessage() = true` also
2. You try to assign `true` to a the call of `launchConfirmationMessage`: There is only one equal sign instead of tow or three

The following is your code slightly corrected:

```js
const confirmationMessage = document.getElementById("message_validation");

// launch confirmationMessage form 
const launchConfirmationMessage = () => {
  confirmationMessage.style.display = "flex";
}

//close confirmationMessage form
const closeConfirmationMessage = () => {
  confirmationMessage.style.display = "none";
}

// TimeOut du confirmationMessage
const timeOutConfirmMess = () => {
  setTimeout(closeConfirmationMessage, 3000);
}


// open and close window after 3s
function confirm() {
  launchConfirmationMessage();
  
  timeOutConfirmMess();
}
console.log(confirm());
```

```css
.message-validation {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 13%;
  top: 41%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(26, 39, 156, 0.9);
  color: white;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="message_validation" class="message-validation">
  Bravo! Votre réservation est prise en compte.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all ! This was my first question on StackOverFlow and it helped me a lot!

Comment: Welcome @WillemJOURET You are welcome to ask :-). If you want to show the people, that their answer helped you, you can mark the post as accepted answer and / or vote it up.